# How to pass XCom message from PythonOperator task to a SparkSubmitOperator task in Airflow

Tags: python, airflow

Say I have a PythonOperator task pushing message to XCom, how can I pull this messages in SparkSubmitOperator?

```
def get_some_value(**kwargs):
    some_value = 10
    return some_value

task1 = PythonOperator(task_id='run_task_1',
                       python_callable=get_some_value,
                       provide_context=True,
                       dag=dag)

task2 = SparkSubmitOperator(
    task_id='run_sparkSubmit_job',
    conn_id='spark_default',
    java_class='com.example',
    application='example.jar',
    name='airflow-spark-job',
    verbose=True,
    application_args=["some_value"],   #<---I want to use some_value from task1 here
    conf={'master':'yarn'},
    dag=dag,
)

task1 >> task2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use xcom_pull on the TaskInstance (ti) macro arg to load the variable returned by task1.  Use the task id "run_task_1" to retrieve the variable:

```
def get_some_value(**kwargs):
    some_value = 10
    return some_value

task1 = PythonOperator(task_id='run_task_1',
                       python_callable=get_some_value,
                       provide_context=True,
                       dag=dag)

task2 = SparkSubmitOperator(
    task_id='run_sparkSubmit_job',
    conn_id='spark_default',
    java_class='com.example',
    application='example.jar',
    name='airflow-spark-job',
    verbose=True,
    application_args=["{{ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='run_task_1')}}"],  
    conf={'master':'yarn'},
    dag=dag,
)
```

application_args supports these jinja templates as it is a template variable: 
see: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/operators/spark_submit_operator.py#L87